# Adding Field using C# winform and ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

How to add a field in featureclass by using C# winform,arcobjects?

It means when we click on command winform should open and afetr field entries it should be add in to table.

Comment: Can you please post some code to show where you're stuck. You can use Windows Forms to access ArcObjects, either as an add-in or a standalone program (I would need to know which one it is) also, is it a local dataset or do you intend to do this over a web interface?

Answer (score 1):

The following function will add a field to a feature class:

```
private void AddField(IFeatureClass fClass, string name, string alias, esriFieldType dataType)
{
    IField newField = new FieldClass();
    IFieldEdit fieldEdit = (IFieldEdit)newField;
    fieldEdit.Name_2 = name;
    fieldEdit.AliasName_2 = alias;
    fieldEdit.Type_2 = dataType;

    fClass.AddField(newField);
}
```

There are, of course, more properties that can be set on the field, this is just a sample of how to set them - the properties ending '_2' on IFieldEdit are the writable ones.